# What is difference between 'self' and 'Number'

Tags: python

I have this code, it doesn't work:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self(self.val + other)
x = Number(5)
x += 1
x += 1
print(x.val)
```

But why does it work when I replace `self` with `Number`?

```
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Number(self.val + other)
x = Number(5)
x += 1
x += 1
print(x.val)
```

Comment: `self` is an *instance*, `Number` is the *class*.

Comment: Please remember that Stackoverflow is _not_ a general help forum. Take the [tour], and read through [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic), to understand why you would use SO. In this case, if you're learning python, and you have questions, keep reading your tutorial or book. If it's unclear after doing that, search the web. SO should be your absolute last resort if you have questions about elementary things relating to any programming language: this is covered by a million tutorials _and the python manual_ already.

Answer (score 0):

### Scenario 1:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self(self.val + other)

x = Number(5)
```

x is an instance of the Number class here, so when you call

```
x += 1
```

you call `__add__` of the `Number` class which has a return value of `self(self.val + other)`. Which results an error because what you are telling here to python is: `return self(5 + 1)`. But doing so would require a `__call__` method defined in the `Number` class. This results the `AttributeError: Number instance has no __call__ method` error message you have seen. If it is unclear why, imagine it like this:

```
x = Number(5)
x(5 + 1)
```

### Scenario 2:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Number(self.val + other)

x = Number(5)
```

x is an instance of the Number class like before.

```
x += 1
```

See what you return now. Your code says `return Number(5 + 1)` so `x` will be a *new instance* of the `Number` class. There may be cases that this is exactly you want but probably not in this case. A "new instance" means that the old `x` is boom, gone, the return value is `Number(6)`, a new object freshly initialized.

```
x += 1
```

Same goes here, x will be a new instance of the Number class, initialized with the values of (6 + 1). Hence this will return 7 and not an error:

```
print(x.val)
```

### What you probably wanted to do is:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    self.val += other
    return self
```

with this the return value would be the same instance of the `Number` class after `__add__` is called. So when you call `x += 1` then `x` will be the same instance you defined at `x = Number(5)`. If you call  this:

```
x = Number(5)
x.name = "test"
x += 1
print(x.name)
```

In this scenario `x` will have a `name` property after `x += 1` since the instance is the same before and after the `__add__`. In **Scenario 2** trying to access `x.name` would result an AttributeError.